# Unread get_field and sub_field always returns null or false

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

Hi guys i having a pretty consisten isue here with some fields

im creating this structure

```
/*Tips*/
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Seccion Tips',
                        'name' => 'sec_mgz_tips',
                        'display' => '',
                        'min' => '',
                        'max' => '',
                        'sub_fields' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5e78e',
                                'label' => 'Tips',
                                'name' => 'sec_bt_tips',
                                'type' => 'repeater',
                                'column_width' => '',
                                   'sub_fields' => array(
                                     array(
                                        'key' => 'field_527178f',
                                        'label' => 'Tip Link',
                                        'name' => 'sec_bt_tip',
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'column_width' => '',
                                        'save_format' => 'id',
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'field_5178f',
                                        'label' => 'Titulo',
                                        'name' => 'sec_bt_tip_title',
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'column_width' => '',
                                        'save_format' => 'id',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'row_min' => '',
                                'row_limit' => 3,
                                'layout' => 'row',
                                'button_label' => 'Agregar Tip',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                   /*Tips end*/
```

Easy this creates a repeater with two fields link and link name
the problem is that when i try to get the data from this field it shows nothing

when i run

```
$subfield = get_field('sec_mgz_tips');
var_dump($subfield);
```

**Prints NULL**

when i run

```
$subfield = get_sub_field('sec_mgz_tips');
var_dump($subfield);
```

**Prints FALSE**

when i run

```
$sections = get_field('bt_secciones');
var_dump($sections);
```

**Prints**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["acf_fc_layout"]=>
    string(11) "sec_bt_post"
    ["sec_post_posts"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(175220)
      [1]=>
      int(175219)
      [2]=>
      int(175062)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["acf_fc_layout"]=>
    string(12) "sec_bt_texto"
    ["sec_c_textos"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["sec_bt_tnumeracion"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["sec_bt_ttitle"]=>
        string(65) "Si se activa, tendrá que agregar el numero de orden al título 1"
        ["sec_bt_tubicaimg"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["sec_bt_tdescripcion"]=>
        string(598) "
8. You hate staying at other people’s houses because you miss your own bed too much. 9. You consider 10pm a really late night. 10. You would never start watching a film after 9pm. 11. You are perfectly capable of NOT binge-watching box sets on Netflix. 12. The best thing about going on holiday is getting home and crawling into your own bed. 13. You get into your pyjamas as soon as you are home for the day.





"
        ["sec_bt_timages"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["sec_bt_timagen"]=>
            int(175232)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["acf_fc_layout"]=>
    string(12) "sec_mgz_tips"
    ["sec_bt_tips"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sec_bt_tip"]=>
        string(6) "LINK 1"
        ["sec_bt_tip_title"]=>
        string(5) "TIP 1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sec_bt_tip"]=>
        string(6) "LINK 2"
        ["sec_bt_tip_title"]=>
        string(5) "TIP 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the array the field does exist so i don’t know why is not printing its values

What could be happening here?

Comment: Are you outside or inside the loop?`

Comment: The result is the same in an outside the loop